# Use case for `&&=`

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

I have seen and used by myself lots of `||=` in Ruby code, but I have almost never seen or used `&&=` in practical application. Is there a use case for `&&=`?

Comment: I hope [`Object#andand`](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) will help you a bit.

Comment: You are in the *use-case*-day today, aren't you?

Comment: @Jueecy.new Don't say him this way. He might be thinking with this topic,let him think. But don't insult him. Hard thinking is always a good ida.

Comment: How about `name &&= name.strip` as a valid use case? One would only want to strip the whitespace of the string and reassign it to name if name is not `nil`.

Comment: Just found [this short post on guarded assignments in Ruby](http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2008/12/16/guarded-assignment-in-ruby/) I've read some time ago again that might interest you.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm Your first comment is a perfect answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Validation of the document such as,

```
a = {'a' => ['string',123]}
```

where the element in `a['a']` should be a `String`. To validate them, I think you can use,

```
def validate(doc, type)
  valid = true
  doc.each{|x|
    valid &&= x.is_a? type
  }
  valid    
end

1.9.3p392 :010 >   validate(a['a'],String) => false
```

Comment: It's not a real use case if there's a much better idiom :) `doc.all? { |x| x.is_a? type }`

Comment: @dbenhur Yeah. That's true. I think the point here I was trying to make is that `&&=` can be used in a reverse way as `||=`. We wanna disable some flag or value if it's needed. :) Correct me if I am not correct here.

Answer (score 3):

Not to be glib, but the obvious use case is any time you would say `x && foo` and desire the result stored back into `x`. Here's one:

```
list = [[:foo,1],[:bar,2]]
result = list.find{ |e| e.first == term }
result &&= result.last  # nil or the value part of the found tuple
```

Comment: This also looks like an interesting case.

Answer (score 0):

any sort of iteration where you want to ensure that the evaluation of a boolean condition on all elements returns true for all the elements.

e.g.

```
 result = true
 array.each do |elem|
   # ...

   result &&= condition(elem)   # boolean condition based on element value
 end
 # result is true only if all elements return true for the given condition
```